# Are two middle peaks considered bimodal or a normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, distribution, normal-distribution

I am wondering if someone could help me determine what type of distribution my data is (normal? bimodal?). See picture below:
[image: Picture of my data distribution]

For context, the data are depth displacements from a fish telemetry study. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This histogram is not fine-grained enough (i.e., not enough bars) to determine that there are "two peaks." If there are really two peaks (which are not visible in the current histogram), you could consider it bimodal. Otherwise, it looks more like a normal distribution.

If you changed the bar interval to 1, it would be easier to see what type of distribution the data follows.

Without a more fine-grained representation of the data, it would be more reasonable to guess that it follows a normal distribution because there is insufficient evidence to suggest it is bimodal.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I forgot I could change the x axis and fiddle with the number of breaks. I did that, and it definitely looks normal, still with those two main peaks, but more bars are present when viewing it in this way. Thank you!

Comment: No problem - if you see a significant dip between high points, you could say it is bimodal. Otherwise, if it just sort of remains elevated in the middle, it is more like a normal distribution